# Writing an xhtml file after reading its content from Jsoup

Tags: java, xhtml, jsoup

I need to be able to manipulate the content of an xhtml file (modify some text within), then write everything back to an xhtml file (could be the same) to be able to user it later. Is it possible with Jsoup or need another library/code to do it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with Jsoup alone. You don't need any extra libraries. Just have a look at the [Jsoup Cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/). If it is really XHTML you could even do it with any XML DOM implementation; Jsoup doesn't come with a formatter for the output so you would just `toString` the modified `Document` with no further control which may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: my question is about how to write the output to a xhtml file, because I tried with a simple FileWriter but I don't think it would be that simple, would it?

Comment: It is. Just `toString` the `Document` and do with the result whatever you want (e.g. `FileWriter`). You don't have any influence over e.g. indentation, that's why I mentioned other XML processing where you typically have such possibiliteis.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT might be your friend in this case. Give it a Google anyway, but it sounds like a good starting point.